# jQuery: How to fix this syntax for a live binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to get this right.

I have form coming in via XHR. I need to be able to attach a submit handler to it once it comes in via XHR, hence the .live() here. The code below actually works, the problem is that an XHR HTTP POST happens (which is good), and then a full page HTTP POST load happens, and that's not good. The return false; seems to be doing nothing. My backend is Rails, but that doesn't mean much in this context. What am I doing wrong in this block of code that's making the HTTP POST happen once for an XHR and once for a full page load? Better way of going about this?

```
$('form[name=clip_form2]').live('submit', function() {
  $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
});
```

My Rails form even has an onsubmit="return false;" handler:

```
  <% form_for(@clip, :url=>group_channel_clip_path(@clip.group_channel,@clip), :method=>:put, :html => {:multipart => true, :name=>'clip_form2', :onsubmit => "return false;"}) do |f| -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name=clip_form2]').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this.attr('action')), $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
    });
});
```

Also this is a really easy to use jquery extension that does this with added features http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: This won't work if the form clip_form2 is not available when the DOM is rendered. some form of .live() or .delegate() still needs to be there.